# Appium: Unable to automate Google Home app using appium

Tags: appium

I tried to run Google home app with the below desired capabilities:

```
desired_caps = 
{    
   "platformName": "android",
   "platformVersion": "6.0",   
   "deviceName": "ZX1D64RN88",    
   "appPackage": "com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app",    
   "appActivity": "com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app.firstlaunch.FirstLaunchWizardActivity",   
   "autoGrantPermissions": "true",    
   "noRest":"true"
}
```

These are the activities I found in Google home app:

```
com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app.firstlaunch.FirstLaunchWizardActivity    
com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app.core.MainActivity 
com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app.homemanagement.settings.HomeSettingsActivity
```

I tried to start the Google home app with all these activities. But no one worked fine for me.

I tried with `adb` command also. But it also didn't work.

This is the command I used to start the app using `adb`:

```
adb shell am start -W -n com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app/com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app.firstlaunch.FirstLaunchWizardActivity -S
```

I got the below error while running with `adb`:

Stopping: `com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app`

Starting: `Intent { cmp=com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app/.firstlaunch.FirstLaunchWizardActivity }`

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {
> flg=0x10000000
> cmp=com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app/.firstlaunch.FirstLaunchWizardActivity
> } from null (pid=21596, uid=2000) not exported from uid 13189
>
> at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
>
> at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
>
> at
> android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAndWait(ActivityManagerNative.java:2804)
>
> at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:877)
>
> at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:359)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
>
> at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:100)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native
> Method)

Can any one suggest how to automate Google Home app using appium?